# The teacher's favorite animal

Tags: visual, rebus, steganography, computer-puzzle

A student asked our teacher about her favorite type of dog during a distance learning meeting. She uploaded the image shown below, said it's our homework to figure that out, and left the call.

What's her favorite type of dog?

[image]

---

<sub>In case it's not obvious, the two-sentence "story" is made up.</sub>

---

Hint #0 I feel obligated to point out:

> The image is smaller [than originally intended](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58310628#58310628). After being informed by Gareth that only smaller images will not get lossily compressed by i.stack.imgur, I had little problems making the image small enough while keeping the same final answer, which may tell you something about the nature of this puzzle.
>
>  Yet, I only realized just now, this makes a certain part in the puzzle useless. I don't think it should be too confusing, though. If anything, it's a little bit easier now.

Hint #1:

> - The symbol in the larger bottom square in the image does **not** represent the letter H
>  - What would you call the large bottom square and the little bottom square? Warning: Maybe keep some synonyms in mind.

Hint #2 (big):

> - One pixel might sometimes represent a long string. How so?
>  - The red subpixel seems to give us characters from a very limited set. Any clues as to what this set is?
>  - Once you understand the basic structure, it should be clear that purely black pixels (i.e. `0,0,0`) are to be ignored.
>  - After all pixels have correctly been parsed, you should have a very long string of characters. Look at *exactly* how long it is. Also think about the set again. We're not looking for a written-out novel as the answer after all...

Hint #3 (colossal):

> Do the green subpixels seem useless, as they're always 0? That's because they are, read hint #0 again. Green would've been used for numbers that need more than one byte (lines below the big boxes)
>  So, red & blue subpixels. Red = Character. Blue = X. Read hint #2 again. The most simple thought regarding that is probably the correct one.
>  Does anything basic about the arrangement of the modified pixels stand out?
>  The bottom part of the blackboard image: Let's say we have 4^2. What is 4 here? What is 2 here? (keep in mind other terms for what 2 might be called there). The `|--|` refers to something already covered in a previous hint. Maybe also look at the characters you get from red again while thinking about this.
>  When you solved the puzzle, you won't see a text stating her favorite dog breed, like e.g. "German Shepherd". You'll see something other than a text showing you what her favorite dog breed is.

Comment: The png format looks like a big spoiler.

Comment: Rot13(Zl thrff vf gung gur oynpx naq erq qbgf ercerfrag fbzr fbeg bs ovanel zrffntr.)

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora Not *directly*, at least. Get the values of all the modified pixels first and then try to make sense of them with the image.

Comment: Perhaps its time for another hint?

Comment: I legit just realized that the dots are a clue and they have color..

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora https://pastebin.com/WAy6fxyU

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since Hints123 were not helpful for me - I was stuck on 1-4 part for 5 days, so I show u at least my progress.
First part:

> You can notice "nongreen pixels" in image
>
>  [image: Detail of image]

Second part:

> Take only them and ignore black pixels after it
>
>  [image: Non green part]

Third part:

> Transfer red part of image to ASCII characters
>
>  `59+95456+59+95456+59+95456+595456+5954545456+5959545456+5959545456+59545956+5959595456+6+6+595959+954o56+595959+954o56+6+65+59+54op56+6+65+59+5o56+5p5+59+5oko56+5pokp56+59+9+5o56+5pokp5+59+9+54o56+65popokp6+59+9+5oko56+65popokp5+59+9+95oko56+65pk5+59+9+9+954oko45+65pokp6+59+9+95oko5+65pkp5+59+9+95o56+65pok5+59+9+95oko5+5pkp+59+9+9+95oko56+5pkp6+9+9+9+95ok045+65plk5+9+9+9+9+9+95ok4o45+5plk5+9+9+9+9+95oko456+5plkp+9+9+9+954ok045+5plplkp6+9+9+` …etc. 4776 characters.

Fourth:

> As you can see, it is too long for a message (24*199 characters long)- still u need to do something with it and something with blue part, which are not ASCII characters, but only like random numbers between 1 and 111+. Adding R+B does give even more weird ASCII (with some above 128, so not correct way).
>  **Length** seems important, but had no idea how to apply it.
>  **Exponent** or **power** seems important, but no idea how to apply it. **Maybe keep some synonyms in mind** so I guess:
>  [image: Synonyms1]
>  [image: Synonyms2]

Fifth:

> Solution is to take **Red part** and repeat it **Blue part** times.
>  Something like `5555555555555555555555555599999999+++9555445555555555555555555555555666666+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++` …etc. 32761 characters. Text now looks like ASCII art) from a distance).
>
>
>  [image: Shiba Inu]
>
>
>  I guess teachers favorite breed is **Shiba Inu**

Sixth:

> Well after converting characters to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), but one by one - it needs to be something like *AAAX*, where *X* is ASCII character from red part of image. It was kind of problem, because I just could not tell program, that it is suddenly different encoding, but it worked after few hours of trying like this:
>  [image: script]
>  It takes red part of image from bytes "RRRRRRRR" but instead I look at them like "00RRBBGG". And separate them to R: "R000R000", B: "B000B000" and G: "G000G000" (it is not exactly like that, but it should give you an idea) -  And it created:
>  [image: Doge]
>  Hope that is understandable.

Comment: Rot13(Gur rkc pyhr vf gurer sbe lbh gb trg gur npghnyyl pbeerpg pbybef. Rkc=Vaqrk. Qvfgnapr orgjrra cvkryf = 64. Fb onfr64 vaqrk. Pbaireg 6-ovg vaqrk ahzore gb pbybe. V. R. Svefg 2 ovgf ner erq, gura terra gura oyhr. Xrrc va zvaq 00=0, 11=255)

Comment: @LukasRotter
Color.FromArgb(((int)Math.Floor(r[count] / 16.0) % 4) * 85, ((int)Math.Floor(r[count] / 4.0) % 4) * 85, ((int)Math.Floor(r[count] / 1.0) % 4 )* 85);
Like that? :D https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDD3d.png

Comment: How did you go from the ASCII string to the final image? I don't follow.

Comment: @jan no, looks like you take the ascii index rather than the base64 index

Comment: @KabirKanhaArora that IS the string it gave me (from far). Almost like ASCII art or something.

Comment: You made that last part very difficult for yourself, but nonetheless it's the correct final image now :)